# How to make a field optional in case of update and required in case of creation react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I want to use the same form to create and update operation. Now in case of create all the fields are required but in case of update I'm hiding the field which can not be updated and I'm also not getting data for that from backend so its empty and that's fine because as its not required after creation.

This is my form schema:

```
  const formSchema = z.object({
  orgId: z.string().min(2, {
    message: 'Organization is required field.',
  }),
  contractId: z.string().min(1, {
    message: 'Contract Id is required field.',
  }),
});
```

Form Defination

```
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      orgId: '',
      contractId: '',
    },
  });
```

Now how I can make the `orgId` in the case of update opeartion optionnal? currently as `orgId` is `required` field, I'm not able to submit the form

Comment: Could you throw more light on it? Please put more code snippets here.